# how to write htaccess redirect even directory exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Help me with htaccess please...

I have following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ c.php [L,QSA]
```

From what I understand this should rewrite even if the directory exists, 
but since I have -Indexes I am receiving a 403 Error ( Access Forbidden ) and 
if I have +Indexes I get the folder index.

I want redirect to c.php even directory exists.

Comment: Hm, now I get 403 only for folders which apache can not read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect all your directories to *c.php* file, use these directives:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule (.+) c.php [R,QSA]
```

To redirect all the unexisting files to *c.php* then use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) c.php [R,QSA]
```